# Google forms Regular Expressions

Tags: forms, expression, google-forms

i'm creating a survey in google forms and cant find any regular expressions for a pin code entry.

The User is being asked a question and can enter 2 pin codes in two text fields. 
I need the Regular expression that contains 4 digits with numbers from 0-9.
Example: 
Textbox1: 1234
Textbox2: 4321

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `\d{4}`
Also set your `Regular Expression` to `Matches`

Answer (score 0):

[0-9]{4}

This should be your regular expression.

```js
function validate() {
  var textField = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
  var regex = /[0-9]{4}/g;
  alert("Valid input: " + regex.test(textField));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox1">
<input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="Validate">
```